# How to I read from a Jupyter iopub socket?

Tags: zeromq, jupyter

I'm trying to learn more about the Jupyter wire protocol.  I want to collect examples of the messages sent on the IOPub socket.

SETUP:

I start a Jupyter console in one terminal then go find the connection file.  In my case the contents are as follows:

```
{
    "shell_port": 62690,
    "iopub_port": 62691,
    "stdin_port": 62692,
    "control_port": 62693,
    "hb_port": 62694,
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "key": "9c6bbbfb-6ad699d44a15189c4f3d3371",
    "transport": "tcp",
    "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
    "kernel_name": ""
}
```

I create a simple python script as follows:

```
import zmq

iopub_port = "62691"
ip = "127.0.0.1"
transport = "tcp"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect(f"{transport}://{ip}:{iopub_port}")

while True:
    string = socket.recv()
    print(string)
```

I open a second terminal and execute the script as follows (it blocks, as expected):

```
python3 script.py
```

And then I switch back to the first terminal (with the Jupyter console running) and start executing code.

ISSUE: Nothing prints on the second terminal.

EXPECTED: Some Jupyter IO messages, or at least some sort of error.

Uh, help?  Is my code fine and this is probably an issue with my config?  Or is my code somehow braindead?

Answer (score 0):

From one of the owners of the Jupyter client repo:

> ZMQ subscriber sockets need a subscription set before they'll receive
>   any messages. The subscription is a prefix of a valid message, and you
>   can set it to an empty bytes string to subscribe to all messages.

e.g. in my case I need to add

```
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
```

before starting the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know if it's possible to capture from IOPub if a process in Jupyter notebook is finished or not?

I'm looking here (http://jupyterlab.github.io/jupyterlab/services/modules/kernelmessage.html) but it is not very clear.